# Delete global variable and release memory from a function

Tags: r, memory

I need to delete a global variable and release the memory it was using from inside a function with R, but none of the options I have tried work.

I have tried rm function with envir parameter and then gc, but gc does not release the memory. I have also tried runing gc in the global environment with eval+envir.

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(col1 = 1:1e6)
cols = paste0('col', 2:100)
for (col in cols){ DT[, col := 1:1e6, with = F] }

rm_and_release <- function(dt){
  dt <- dt[sample(1e6, 9e5, FALSE)]
  print(gc())
  rm(DT, envir = globalenv())

  print(gc())
}

rm_and_release(DT)
```

The result is the following

```
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   661556  35.4    1168576   62.5   1143443   61.1
Vcells 96303112  734.8   146725516 1119.5 146722586 1119.5
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   661569  35.4    1168576   62.5   1143443   61.1
Vcells 96303114  734.8   146725516 1119.5 146722586 1119.5
```

I expected the second gc() to liberate more memory, since at that moment there is only one dataset, because the global DT has been removed.

I need to liberate RAM inside the function because the function generates more datasets and it runs out of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found some code that works

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(col1 = 1:1e6)
cols = paste0('col', 2:100)
for (col in cols){ DT[, col := 1:1e6, with = F] }

rm_and_release <- function(){
  dt <- copy(DT)
  dt <- dt[sample(1e6, 9e5, FALSE)]
  print(gc())
  rm(DT, envir = globalenv())

  print(gc())
}

rm_and_release()
```

It results in

```
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   865272  46.3    1442291   77.1   1280599   68.4
Vcells 96733883 738.1  167167064 1275.4 147681076 1126.8
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells   865173  46.3    1442291   77.1   1280599   68.4
Vcells 46731629 356.6  133733651 1020.4 147681076 1126.8
```

I think it's very ugly not inserting DT as an argument of the function, but at least in this scenario the memory is lowered from 738Mb to 356Mb, which is crucial to what I'm doing

Answer (score 0):

Use the `list=` argument of `rm` like this:

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(col1 = 1:1e6)
cols = paste0('col', 2:100)
for (col in cols){ DT[, col := 1:1e6, with = F] }

rm_and_release <- function(dt){
  dt <- dt[sample(1e6, 9e5, FALSE)]
  print(gc())
  rm(list = "DT", envir = globalenv())

  print(gc())
}

rm_and_release(DT)
exists("DT")
## [1] FALSE
```

### Note

Here is the log when I run it (on Windows):

```
> library(data.table)
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells 1075660 57.5    1899034 101.5  1899034 101.5
Vcells 2609137 20.0   91310117 696.7 99059673 755.8
> DT = data.table(col1 = 1:1e6)
> cols = paste0('col', 2:100)
> for (col in cols){ DT[, col := 1:1e6, with = F] }
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
> 
> rm_and_release <- function(dt){
+   dt <- dt[sample(1e6, 9e5, FALSE)]
+   print(gc())
+   rm(list = "DT", envir = globalenv())
+ 
+   print(gc())
+ }
> 
> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells  1076769  57.6    1899034 101.5  1899034 101.5
Vcells 53024698 404.6   91310117 696.7 99059673 755.8
> rm_and_release(DT)
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells  1075902  57.5    1899034  101.5  1899034 101.5
Vcells 97613454 744.8  134081733 1023.0 99059673 755.8
           used  (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells  1075901  57.5    1899034  101.5  1899034 101.5
Vcells 97613454 744.8  160978079 1228.2 99059673 755.8
> exists("DT")
[1] FALSE
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb) max used  (Mb)
Ncells 1075669 57.5    1899034 101.5  1899034 101.5
Vcells 2613271 20.0  128782463 982.6 99059673 755.8
> ## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Surely this is bad too, removing an object named `DT` regardless of what the input to the function is.

Comment: The poster did not describe his intent but only gave code and that code is attempting to remove `DT` regardless of `dt`  so I just fixed it to actually remove it while keeping what seems to be the original intent.   If that is not his intent then the question needs to be fixed.

Comment: I have tried your code but I find that the object is deleted but the memory is not released, both gc() show that the memory in use is around 730 mb. In the second gc() we have one data.table less, so there should be less memory in use. Thanks.

Comment: The log is shown in the Note at the end. The Ncells and Vcells have not changed showing any intermediate memory allocation was released.

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck. However memory is not released until the function has ended, I need to release it before, because my real function uses more memory at the end and runs out of it. I'm not sure if my intentions are clear. I have posted an answer (not too pretty) where memory is released inside the function.